# Livewire Routes Slug Parameter with wrong url generate automatically when using Pagination

Tags: laravel, routes, pagination, slug

I have problems with pagination using livewire.
If I use Livewire Pagination without parameter on Routes like this :

```
Route::get('/listNews', ListNews::class);
```

It works just fine, for the URL given :
http://abc.test/listNews?page=2

But in the other case, if I use parameter slug on Routes like this :

```
Route::get('/listNews/{slug}', ListNews::class);
```

The url automatically change to :
'http://abc.test/listNews/listNews/slug-example?page=2'

That should be :
'http://abc.test/listNews/slug-example?page=2'

This only happens with Livewire page that using Slug as Routes Parameter

That URL should be like :
'http://abc.test/listNews/slug-example?page=2'

Without double link 'http://abc.test/listNews/listNews/slug-example?page=2' when using pagination livewire with slug routes parameter

Comment: Please show your ListNews component code.